# Адаптивный сайт по фэн-шую

Tags: html, css, drupal, адаптивная-верстка, drupal8

Настала пора призадуматься о том, как будет выводится разрабатываемый мною сайт на различных устройствах. Начитался статей вдоволь, попутно нашел небольшой список дополнительных модулей, которые помогают в верстке:

- Bootstrap Layouts
- Chaos Tool Suite
- Page Manager
- Panels
- Paragraphs

Но, увы, даже с помощью них не могу понять, как мне сделать правильную **для меня** верстку. В большинстве важных советов слышу одно и то же - "используй CSS". Но, имхо, это не делает сайт адаптивным - это делает (может делать) адаптивной только верстку. А разница есть. Например, отдавать 25-меговый контент по бесплатному вай-фаю, или 1-меговый по мобильному инету. Конечно, программно на HTML/JS определить характеристики инет-канала невозможно, но можно программно определить физические характеристики окна вывода сайта в дюймах, используя ширину/высоту в пикселях и [DPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279749/detecting-the-system-dpi-ppi-from-js-css). И уже на этом этапе решать, что грузить. Таким образом, напрашивается одно решение - в каждой странице должен быть JavaScript-[загрузчик](http://api.jquery.com/load/). Который сперва определяет, что грузить, и только потом грузит. Кстати, так ли это работает в многочисленных адаптивных темах? Если "нет", то как?

Собственно, что мне нужно:

1. Определить набор размещений (Layout)
2. Определить набор геометрических размеров окон вывода в дюймах
3. Мочь привязать часть размещений из набора к любой странице сайта - исходя из набора геометрических размеров окон вывода
4. Желательно мочь передать в любую вьюху параметрами - используемое размещение

Как я понимаю, п.1 можно сделать с помощью DS? Как-то можно и п.4, наверное через контекстные фильтры? Как? А вот как решить весь вопрос в том виде, как я описал?

Comment: Может я отстал от жизни, но если главная страница со всем контентом весит больше 10Мб, то для меня это повод задуматься, что я что-то делаю не так.

Comment: Когда заказчик требует фото-галерею с автоскролом и ресайзом на весь экран - тут думай, не думай, а грузить надо.Так вот, на физически небольших устройствах можно немного смухлевать и дать картинку чуть меньшего разрешения (и это правильно), все равно у него с нереально высоким DPI это будет почти незаметно. А что делать на full hd десктопах?

Comment: 1. Использовать ядрёный модуль Responsive Image.

2. Картинку делать плохого качества и накладывать на неё маску из точек, полосок, чтобы не было видно расплывчатых пикселей.

3. Сказать клиенту, что он неправ. Что это минус его клиенты, минус поиск.

Comment: @VVS , картинки - это еще не все. Для начала предлагаю ознакомится со статьей, которую мне присоветовали на соседнем ресурсе - https://agente.ru/blog/adaptive-vs-responsive-web-design
Даже, в условиях угрозы уличения в "клоакинге", я считаю - адаптивный дизайн важен и нужен. Вопрос "как" в рамках Друпала 8 ...

Comment: советую посмотреть на тему adaptivetheme или bootstrap. Первая позволяет в ui настроить адаптивность, частично, для views решения пока не обнаружил.

Comment: Самый [фен шуйный](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/mobile) мануал. И про отзывчивость, адаптивность, мобильность.